# Strip extra data from email imaplib

Tags: python, email, imaplib

I have some simple code to read the first email from the inbox:

```
import imaplib

server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('server.com', 993)

email = 'email@email.com'
password = 'password123'

server.login(email, password)

stat, count = server.select('Inbox')

stat, data = server.fetch(count[0], 'BODY[TEXT]')

print(data[0][1].decode('utf-8'))
```

Using this code on a gmail account returns:

```
Test email
123
```

But on a non-gmail account, I get something like this:

```
--000000000000e4029f05be24b221
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Test email
123

--000000000000e4029f05be24b221
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr"><div>Test email</div><div>123<br></div></div>

--000000000000e4029f05be24b221--
```

Both emails only contain `Test email 123`, so why is the non-gmail one have some much other stuff, and is there anyway to get rid of it, or ignore it?

Comment: The "issue" is that your other example has a both a `text/plain` and a HTML version of the content included. Gmail might be only returning one of these (although I'd think they'd return both as well). You can use the `email` module to parse and unpack a multipart mime message (see [example of how to unpack a MIME message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)).